# Simplest way to make java crud app

Tags: java

I am trying study web development using Java but its seems very intimidating. all the tutorials are showing very complex methods, even the sample applications that came with NetBeans. I have some experience working with PHP but none with java.

Is there any simple way to use java on the server to just accept post requests and save to database and then display data from database without using things like javaServer faces?

Is it necessary to use frameworks like spring?

Pls forgive if i am asking stupid questions. i cant seem to find where to start learning from and tutorials seem too confusing.

Links to any good article will be very helpful

Thanks

Comment: You never *need* to have a framework for DB access.  If you did, how would the frameworks exist?  :)

Comment: @cHao ya that's a good point :-)

Comment: I'm slightly bias since I really like Grails but it's super simple to make a CRUD application. http://grails.org/learn

Comment: The framework is greatly simplifies development, without it you have to write much code yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this purpose you should be familiar with the Servlet API, and preferably also with MVC frameworks and so on.

For the whole world to be a bit more straightforward for you and to steer away from the average-PHP-community-drawbacks (e.g. nobody tells you how to code well), I'd recommend to read **[THIS](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Clean%20Code%3a%20A%20handbook%20of%20agile%20software%20craftsmanship%20pdf%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a)** book.

But first of all, start **[HERE](http://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/)** and then move on to **[THIS SITE](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/hibernate-tutorials/)**.

The other way around (talking about DB access, not the web service here) is using raw SQL via **[JDBC](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jdbc-tutorials/)** which I won't recommend unless you have a good reason for it and you're already familiar with using a DB the right way (*mysql* and *mysqli* libs of PHP won't necessarily drive you the right path; *PDO* most probably will however).

Of course you don't necessarily need to use frameworks, but you're (actually in any language) way better off using them. Yes, probably the closest thing to the "nobrainers-php-methodology" (mindless coding; wiring UI, DB access and business logic together in a single file; etc.) is using the Servlet API, and then through a **[java.sql.Connection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html)** send your GET/POST data directly to the DB via JDBC. But doing so is slightly worse than cruelly murdering cute little squirrels/bunnies/kitties/insert_your_favourite_cute_creature_here

You'll also need a servlet container, most common of which is Apache Tomcat.

Comment: PS.: Feel free to contact me as you like; depending on my spare time, I'm happy to help you with learning Java EE (btw I'd recommend using **[Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/keplersr1)**)

Answer (score 1):

To learn Web Developing with Java Play Framework 1 is very nice:

- Step by Step guide for a cool blog: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.7/guide1
- Documentation: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.7/home
- CRUD module documentation: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.7/crud
- You get compile feedback directly in the browser.
- Run your tests in the browser.
- No redeployment to containers necessary/hot deployment.
- No servlets.

Play 2 is already around, but going through Play 1 is much simpler if you are new a the Java world.